# What is complete structures of the photonic quantum computers?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization, photonics

I am interested in studying quantum computers based on photonic integrated circuits. I am looking for a site, article, book, or material that will introduce the process of its implementation step by step.

For example, if this process is going to be done step by step over a thousand steps, what are these steps exactly? Actually, I just want to know what the step-by-step process is to build a quantum computer from start to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 7 of [Nielsen and Chaung](https://profmcruz.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-nielsen-chuang.pdf) goes through (some of) the physical realizations of quantum computers.

However, it's important to note the sheer complexity involved in building a quantum computer from scratch. Building a quantum computer is not a linear process that can be captured in a thousand, or even several thousand, straightforward steps. Instead, the process is multidimensional, spanning across various scientific disciplines such as theoretical physics, materials science, engineering, computer science, and more.

As mentioned briefly, there are many physical realizations of qubits (hence different hardware), such as [superconducting qubits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_quantum_computing), [trapped ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapped-ion_quantum_computer#:%7E:text=Ions%2C%20or%20charged%20atomic%20particles,interacting%20through%20the%20Coulomb%20force) and [quantum dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot). For [NISQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy_intermediate-scale_quantum_era#:%7E:text=The%20current%20state%20of%20quantum,enough%20to%20achieve%20quantum%20supremacy.) devices, the choice of qubit depends somewhat on the specific application, amongst other things. However, there is no general consensus as to which approach is the best approach (see [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34055/what-is-the-optimal-hardware-for-quantum-computing-and-what-factors-contribute)).

So even if it were easy to list the steps to build a quantum computer in any one of these approaches, the steps would also be somewhat fluid and subject to change, as advancements are made and new methods discovered.
Due to this, producing a definitive step-by-step guide would not just difficult but perhaps somewhat premature.

Comment: The section in Nielsen and Chuang is mostly unrelated to this question. That's the scheme for discrete-variable quantum computing using photonics (dual-rail encoding, etc.), while Borealis and its ilk are for continuous-variable quantum computer (cubic phase gates, GKP states, etc). The rest of this answer is great

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Thanks for pointing out the oversight! I’ve edited that part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In fact, I am aware of the extent of discussion and planning of new ideas, as well as many innovations in this field. I want to follow just a path from the beginning to the end of to study. that I can advance my study path step by step. thanks again for your response